# Add a page to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently in the process of building my own WordPress plugin.So i need to create a new page(or post) that will be automatically added to word press when the plugin is activated.And this will be removed when plugin is deactivated.Content in the page is what content i am typing in the plugin.
 HOW CAN I DO THAT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use wp_insert_post function to create page or post  check this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

ex.

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'My post',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

// Insert the post into the database
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post);
```

you can use $post_id withing add_post_meta or update_post_meta or use post_meta varible to install and uninstall the page.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [**this**](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-create-a-new-page-with-the-plugin-im-building)? There's some code referenced in the linked post for dealing with page creation. There's also the [**codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).